# User input with linear and binary searching in java

Tags: user-input, binary-search, linear-search

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user to input the size of the array the user wants to create, and then asks the user to fill the array with elements, and then it should display the array with its elements and, ask the user to conduct a search for an integer. It should conduct a linear and binary search, while displaying how many probes it took to determine is the element is in the array. So far the only output i have gotten is that the element has not been found. If you could look at my code and see what the problem is, because i have tried for hours and i have changed everything i can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Searching
{
public static int[] anArray = new int[100];

private int numberOfElements;

public int arraySize = numberOfElements;

public String linearSearch(int value)
{

    int count = 0;

    boolean valueInArray = false;

    String indexOfValue = "";

    System.out.print("The Value was Found in: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {   
        if(anArray[i] == value)
        {   
            valueInArray = true;

            System.out.print(i + " ");

            indexOfValue += i + " ";

        }
        count ++;
    }
    if(!valueInArray)
    {
        indexOfValue = " None found";

        System.out.print(indexOfValue);
    }
    System.out.println("\nIt took " + count + " probes with a linear search to find");

    return indexOfValue;

}

public void binarySearch(int value)
{

    int min = 0;
    int max = arraySize - 1;
    int count = 0;

    while(min <= max)
    {

        int mid = (max + min) / 2;

        if(anArray[mid] < value) min = mid + 1;

        else if(anArray[mid] > value) max = mid - 1;

        else
        {

            System.out.println("\nFound a Match for " + value + " at Index " + mid);

            min = max + 1;
        }
        count ++;
    }   
    System.out.println("It took " + count + " probes with a binary search to find");
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input the number of elements in your Array");
    int numberOfElements = scan.nextInt();

    if(numberOfElements <= 0)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int[] anArray = new int[numberOfElements];

    System.out.println("\nEnter " + numberOfElements + " Integers");
    for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i ++)
    {
        System.out.println("Int # " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        anArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("\nThe integers you entered are: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i ++)        // for loop used to print out each element on a different line
    {
        System.out.println(anArray[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Which element would you like to find?");
    int value = scan.nextInt();

    Wee3Q2JOSHBALBOA newArray = new Wee3Q2JOSHBALBOA();

    newArray.linearSearch(3);

    newArray.binarySearch(value);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm I am not sure you are using an array the correct way, you see an Array is a set size and I dont think you can expand like they way you are doing...

Instead try setting the size of the array to certain length. 
Or use vectors